# Adding Vector Components using an array

Tags: c, arrays

The question is as follows: Given the vector size and two vectors “a” and “b” of that size (all being entered by user),
calculate the sum and the difference of these two vectors as a vector “c”. To do that,
add/subtract corresponding coordinates of two vectors.
You must implement the following functions:

void addVectors(double a[], double b[], double c[], int size);

void subtractVectors(double a[], double b[], double c[], int size);

What I have written is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

void addVectors(double a[], double b[], double c[], int size){
    printf("Adding the vectors we get: \n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    c[i] = b[i] + a[i];
    printf("%f, ", c[i]);}}

void subtractVectors(double a[], double b[], double c[], int size){
    printf("\nSubtracting the vectors we get: \n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    c[i] = b[i] - a[i];
    printf("%f, ", c[i]);}}

int main()

{
    int size, i;
    printf("Please enter the size of your vectors: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    double a[size], b[size], c[size];
    printf("Please enter the coordinates of vector A: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        scanf("%f", &a[i]);}
    printf("Please enter the coordinates of vector B: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        scanf("%f", &b[i]);}
    addVectors(a, b, c, size);
    subtractVectors(a, b, c, size);
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone could let me know why my output is all zeros that would be much appreciated.

Comment: wrong format specifier for `scanf`. `%f` is for `float`, `%lf` for `double` - Your compiler should have printed warnings about that

Comment: Also, using just `"%f"` will not skip the whitespace or other non-numeric characters in between your values... So you're likely not even inputting the numbers you think you are. Checking the return value of `scanf` is generally a good idea.